# Workaround for insert on duplicate delete for table with all columns using foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I want to store users' bookmarked product pages into the database like the Star-bookmarking to the left of my post, which can toggle between bookmarked and unbookmarked on click. Can I use two columns to achieve that, one for users' ids and one for products' ids? But how can I delete a record when people unbookmark the page, given that both fields,user id and product id, are foreign keys?

PS. UPDATING foreign key statements

Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE user_favorite
    (`USER_ID` int, `MODEL_ID` int)
;

INSERT INTO user_favorite
    (`USER_ID`,`MODEL_ID`)
VALUES
    (1, '2'),
    (2, '3'),
    (3, '1'),
    (4, '1'),
    (5, '1')
;

CREATE TABLE USER_ID
    (`USER_ID` int, `USER` varchar(20))
;

INSERT INTO USER_ID
    (`USER_ID`,`USER`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Tom'),
    (2, 'Mary'),
    (3, 'Paul'),
    (4, 'Peter'),
    (5, 'John')
;


CREATE TABLE MODEL_ID
    (`MODEL_ID` int, `MODEL` varchar(20))
;

INSERT INTO MODEL_ID
    (`MODEL_ID`,`MODEL`)
VALUES
    (1, 'ToyA'),
    (2, 'ToyB'),
    (3, 'ToyC')
;

ALTER TABLE user_favorite
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_userfav_user_id 
FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID) REFERENCES USER_ID(USER_ID) 
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE user_favorite
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_userfav_model_id 
FOREIGN KEY (MODEL_ID) REFERENCES Model_ID(MODEL_ID) 
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: to make deletes easy, add an `id auto_increment` to the `user_favorites`. with the id field it should be easy to identify the record you like to remove.

Comment: @devanand, I saw it in another thread that there is no such thing as `INSERT ON DUPLICATE DELETE` in mysql, do I need to use two queries, `INSERT IGNORE` and `REPLACE` or create a trigger?

Answer (score 2):

Bookmarking, `INSERT`, and unbookmarking, `DELETE`, are 2 separate operations, there isn't a toggle function.

The only way of doing what you describe without a `TRIGGER` is to add another flag column `reversed TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0` and putting a composite `UNIQUE` key on (`user_id`,`model_id`) and treating `reversed=1` or no row as unbookmarked.

Then you can run:

```
INSERT INTO user_favorite (user_id,model_id) VALUES (**user_id**,**model_id**)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE reversed = NOT reversed;
```

This will update any `AUTO_INCREMENT` each time it is run, but will give a bookmark history of sorts.

I would recommend, however, implementing the feature in the simpler way described by *fancyPants* below.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what your problem is. You want to delete bookmarkings, right?

A foreign key just checks if there's a parent row when you insert.
In your case this means, that you can not insert into table `user_favorite` values that are not present in either table `user_id` or `model_id`. Nothing more. You can delete from `user_favorite` anything you like without any consequences. Tables `user_id` and `model_id` are not affected.

You added

```
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

What this does is, that when you delete for example user Tom from table `user_id`, all his bookmarkings are deleted as well, which is probably what you want, since they don't make sense anymore anyway - bookmarkings without the user who bookmarked them.
Same for `update`. If you wish to update a model_id in table model_id, the foreign key constraint just ensures, that the bookmarkings don't become useless. It updates the `model_id` in table `user_favorite` as well.

All you have to do to implement your bookmarking feature, is to insert a record with `user_id` and `model_id` in `user_favorite` when one clicks the star, and delete the same entry when he clicks the star again. That's it.